# Jquery post all form data onblur from specific form

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to POST/GET data onBlur from form. My basic need is to make it possible to post form-data (user input) and all the hidden fields......and these field values may vary. But only in the specific form, not all forms.

All I basicly need is to POST form-data to a php-script (that's my home field......hoping to develop in jQuery)

Here is an example (which may be changed so it can be jQuery friendly if needed)

```
<form name=\"username\">
    <input id=\"username\" type=\"text\" value=\"111111111111\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"type\" value=\"username\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"val1\" value=\"???\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"val2\" value=\"???\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"val3\" value=\"???\">
</form>

<form name=\"firstname\">
    <input id=\"firstname\" type=\"text\" value=\"222222222222\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"type\" value=\"firstname\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"val1\" value=\"???\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"val2\" value=\"???\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"val3\" value=\"???\">
</form>

<form name=\"lastname\">
    <input id=\"lastname\" type=\"text\" value=\"333333333\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"type\" value=\"lastname\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"val1\" value=\"???\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"val2\" value=\"???\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"val3\" value=\"???\">
</form>`
```

Help me Obi Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope! :)
Looking forward to hear from you all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#username, #firstname, #lastname').on('blur', function () {
         Var data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        $.post(url, data, function() {});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I will test if. What if I do not know which form (name) I am in, so I kind of get the form-name when "blurring". This may affect the "$('#username, #firstname, #lastname')".

Cheers Nikolaj

You couldn't have known this so I am sorry that I did not say it earlier, but how would I get form-name or eventually just the hidden value named "type", then I could restrict data to php.......hope you get my point? :)

Comment: When we serialize and post the values all hidden elements will be included in the posted data.

Comment: Thanks alot. NOW I understood :) The simple solution already there! Thanks @Arjun for your help :)